# Wordpress filter on adding meta?

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, I need to program it such that anytime someone enters or updates a post meta called "start_date", a bit of code is run on what is entered before it is saved.

I need to take what is entered and convert it to a unix timestamp.

Is there a way to do this?

If not, is there a way to add the code on publish or update of the post such that it checks for that meta and updates it if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating the metaboxes and custom fields with your plugin, you can do the following. Otherwise, it depends on how their saving the data as it could overwrite yours.

Here's something to get you started though depending on what the case is.

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_the_post_meta', 100, 2);
function update_the_post_meta($post_id, $post) {

    if ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) { return; }
    if ( defined('DOING_CRON') && DOING_CRON ) { return; }
    if ($post->post_type == 'revision') { return; }

    if ( isset($_REQUEST['start_date']) ) :
        //do your timestamp code here and save it in $timestamp
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'start_date', $timestamp, true) or update_post_meta($post_id, 'start_date', $timestamp); 
    else :
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'start_date');
    endif;

}
```

Right now the priority of the add_action is set to 100 (the higher the number, the less priority it has). So, if you're trying to override someone else's function, you may need to increase the priority number. Also, this is assuming the name of the input field is "start_date".